# How do I expose the Documents Directory?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to expose my app’s documents directory in the Files app included with iOS. I thought adding “ Application supports iTunes file sharing” in the info.plist file would do the trick, but no. Anyone know how to do this?

Just to be clear, the user should be able to open the Files app, tap My iPhone, and see my apps documents directory.

Thanks all.

Comment: I think you also need Supports opening documents in place. And you might also need an actual document type but I’m not sure.

Comment: See [Does your app need a file provider extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider)

Comment: @Paulw11 "You don't need a File Provider extension to provide access to documents stored locally"

Comment: Yes. The article I linked to explains this in the section I referrred to. It explains what you do need to do.

Comment: Hey thanks Paulw11. I just need to add the correct keys. Thanks guys.

Answer (score -1):

I was missing an info.plist key, or two. From the link Paulw11 gave me:

> To give other apps access to the files in your Documents directory, just set the proper keys in your app's Info.plist file. You can either set the UISupportsDocumentBrowser key (for document browser-based apps), or set both the UIFileSharingEnabled and LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace keys.

> These keys enable other apps to open and edit the contents of your Documents directory in place. Your files also appear in both the Files app and the document browser. For more information, see the UIDocumentBrowserViewController class.

So the intention of these keys seems to be giving other apps access to my app’s files. Letting the user see them the sort of a side effect.

Answer (score -1):

"Application supports iTunes file sharing" set to "YES" solves the described problem on iOS 17.1.1. Please make sure you properly save file into the Documents folder.

```
let documentsDirectoryUrl = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
let fileUrl = documentsDirectoryUrl.appendUniqueFileName(name!.removingPercentEncoding!)
try bytes.write(to: fileUrl, options: [.atomicWrite])
```